# Hibernate CRUD à la Ruby on Rails' Scaffolding

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, hibernate, jsp, jsf

Do you know of any tool that would do like Ruby on Rails' Scaffolding (create simple CRUD pages for any particular class to allow quickly populating a database with dummy data), only which used Java classes with Hibernate for database access, and JSP/JSF for the pages?

It is a drag when you are programming one part of an application, but need data that can only be added with another part that is not ready yet, or very cumbersomely by directly inserting it into the DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Grails](http://grails.org/) is a very nice Rails-like framework built on top of Spring MVC.  For persistence, they use [GORM](http://grails.org/GORM), which is basically an ActiveRecord-like framework built on top of Hibernate.  Pretty slick.

If you already have Hibernate entities, they can actually be used immediately in Grails with no additional work.

Answer (score 4):

You can try **Telosys Tools**, an Eclipse plugin for 
code generation (scaffolding) working from an existing database 
with customizable Velocity templates.
It's very simple and easy to use.

The tutorial for code generation with Spring MVC and Spring Data is here : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/

See also : http://tools.telosys.org/

Eclipse Marketplace : http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/telosys-tools

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late on this one but it popped up in the "Related" links →

JBoss Seam and it's [Seam Gen](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.CR1/reference/en-US/html_single/#gettingstarted) tasks are exactly what you are looking for (Hibernate + JSF). You can generate an entire web app from a Hibernate fronted database in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

you can use grails. Grails tries to be Groovy on Rails -- uses Rails behind the scene for scaffolding, etc. Since you can pretty much write full scale java code in a groovy class, you can have the CAKE and EAT IT too.

Answer (score 0):

Grails is somewhat different from Rails, even though it was based on Rails and has a similar feel. Grails uses spring to help wire your services together. The environment is not only dynamic (with Groovy) but also allows you to use Java (static environment) as well. It is really cool, especially if you're coming from a java environment. The Grails folks took the Rails idea and expanded it using the Domain Driven Model. Rails is still data model centric where you have to deal a lot with the database to create your objects (which is called a model), where as Grails allows you to design applications using the true domain object model where you deal with objects from the domain class' perspective instead of the database.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good tutorial [here](http://netbeans.dzone.com/news/generation-jsf-20-crud-in-netbeans-68) on how to do this in Netbeans. I've used this wizard before with good results. Out of the box you can select which persistance framework to use and the JSF pages it produces are quite nice and clean.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) + [AspectJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspectj) + [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_(Java)) + [CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) = [**Spring Roo**](http://www.springsource.org/roo) [RAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_application_development) framework.

Give it a try.